# Driving a DVI monitor from a monochrome source

Tags: power-electronics, display, adapter, computers

I have a plasma display EL8358MS that is defective (burnt out.) The display has a signal convertor with these inputs:

```
+H_SYNC
-H_SYNC
+DOT_CLK
-DOT_CLK
+VIDEO_DATA
-VIDEO_DATA
+V_SYNC
-V_SYNC
```

I wonder if these signals can drive the DVI input of the LCD.  The original panel was 640X200 pixel. If this may be possible I can make some oscilloscope captures for the signals for timings and voltage levels.

Answer (score 0):

DVI does not have the signals you list.

It is unlikely a DVI compatible interface.

Even if you could convert the interface, it is unlikely that a DVI monitor supports the 640x200 resolution at whatever horizontal and vertical rates your device outputs.

Which means you need some sort of scaler chip to convert it to some standard resolution accepted by DVI monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor and display are different things. A monitor contains a display. So you can drive a monitor with DVI, but you can't drive a display with DVI.

There must be a driver circuit which takes DVI, VGA, HDMI, Composite etc. "video input" and convert it to "pixel data" that the display accepts.